# How to print from musicnotes.com on linux

Tags: chrome, printing, music

musicnotes.com won't let me print because it says:

> "We don't support printing from this device or browser."

I'm using chrome, so there isn't any difference between printing on linux or any other os... it seems musicnotes.com is just being overly restrictive.

How do I get it to print the music I paid for without buying a copy of microsoft windows?

Comment: I worked on a (different) project where some one was writing that code. I asked why, they said it was a requirement.I said where, they pointed at "it must work in microsoft IE7 and above". I asked where does it say that it must not work in other browsers. They said  that code. I asked why, they said it was a requirement.I said where, they pointed at "it must work in microsoft IE7 and above". It took an age to get that code removed.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor it pains me to work with that type of requirements driven software monkey. This comes from being rewarded for finishing tasks, writing code, and not rewarded for thinking, or for removing code, or for removing wrong requirements, or for doing the right thing. I blame tools like jira. My solution is often to enter a jira task to remove the offending code. Since they would get credit for closing jira tasks they will often do what I ask even if it is not 'driven by a requirement'. Asking directly is pointless as they get no visibility in their jira management only reward structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your `User-Agent` in browser so that fake your operating system.
I tested with [User-Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/) (for firefox) in Fedora and changed it to Windows and was able to download a free music sheet pdf.

Comment: Thanks. i knew the answer, but felt surprised it wasn't asked and answered here. I added musicnotes.com to the permanent spoof list and I'll not have to remember to do it again. Shame on musicnotes.com!

Comment: @poleguy it is really surprising why do they care...why OS matters to them...

Comment: @dinarysta I wonder if they didn't pay the web development platform company for linux support, because it's extra, or some other degenerate reason. I'm very cynical about companies doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [their website](https://help.musicnotes.com/hc/en-us/articles/201768497-Do-you-support-Linux-or-Ubuntu-or-other-non-PC-non-Mac-operating-systems-): "This is due to various printing issues we encountered during the development process." And it's true: the samples (free) do not look very good at all (although the paid PDFs are OK, of course).

I found things worked much better with the ["User-Agent Switcher and Manager"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/) by Ray (recommended by Firefox)

Comment: So you're just suggesting a different user-agent switcher? What advantage does this have for musicnotes.com? Why is this any better than the accepted answer? Do the sample printouts really look better under windows?